# Netsuite Sales order status (webservice)

Tags: netsuite

I have a problem with orderstatus when I create Sales order using webservice.

```
SalesOrder salesOrder = new SalesOrder();
            salesOrder.otherRefNum = order.PONumber;
            salesOrder.shippingCost = 0;
            salesOrder.shippingCostSpecified = true;
            salesOrder.orderStatus = SalesOrderOrderStatus._pendingFulfillment;
            salesOrder.orderStatusSpecified = true;
```

After save Sales order the status is always Pending approval.

https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2017_1/schema/record/salesorder.html?mode=package

This field contains the default status for your sales orders, as specified on the Company Preference page. If your company uses the approval process for sales orders, Pending Approval is your default. If your company does not use the approval process, Pending Fulfillment is your default. You can change the status for each sales order here if needed. Available values are: _pendingApproval _pendingFulfillment Important: You cannot set orderStatus to _closed if you want to close a sales order. Instead, you must close all the line items on the sales order. The order status of the sales order will then change to closed.

I can not change default status. Is any reason why i can not set _pendingFulfillment status via webservice?

Answer (score 0):

you could potentially use a workflow, that would trigger on a webservice, to change the status.
I would also check workflows to see if there is any active on the SO (which is often the case).